# How to cast PHP object to C++ Object

Tags: php, c++, tcp

I have a TCP server I wrote in c++. It is designed to send an object of fixed size and works perfectly in every way but one. When I connect to the tcp server via php in a web browser I am not sure how to cast my object for transmitting like I do in c++.

In c++ I use the following:

```
  #define MAX_MESSAGE 256

  enum MESSAGE_TYPE {NO_TYPE, COMMAND, REQUEST, RESPONSE, POST, SETUP, QUIT};
  enum PAYLOAD_TYPE {NO_LOAD, INT, UINT, FLOAT, DOUBLE, CHAR};

  struct Message{

  MESSAGE_TYPE  type;
  int           client;
  PAYLOAD_TYPE  p_type;

  char          payload[MAX_MESSAGE];

  Message (MESSAGE_TYPE _type, int _client){
    type    = _type;
    client  = _client;
  }

  /* UNSIGNED INT PAYLOAD */
  Message (MESSAGE_TYPE _type, int _client, unsigned int value){
    type    = _type;
    client  = _client;
    p_type  = UINT;
    memcpy(payload, &value, sizeof(unsigned int));
  }

  /* FLOAT PAYLOAD */
  Message (MESSAGE_TYPE _type, int _client, float value){
    type    = _type;
    client  = _client;
    p_type  = FLOAT;
    memcpy(payload, &value, sizeof(value));
  }

  }
```

and then cast it to a char* on transmit like so..

```
Message m(SETUP,id);
channel->cwrite((char *)&m, sizeof(m)+1 );
```

I am now trying to create a web client for sending commands to the server and therefore individual devices (Custom IOT yada yada). I can connect to the server with PHP but not sure what I need to do to cast my Message object in PHP so the server can understand it and then recieve a Message object back from the server.

Things that confuse me: when I check the size of a similar PHP object...

```
class Message{

  public $type;
  public $client;
  public $p_type;
  public $payload;

  function __construct (){
    $this->type    = 1;    // Fixed Test Value
    $this->client  = 22;   // Fixed Test Value
    $this->p_type  = 1;    // Fixed Test Value
    $this->payload = new SplFixedArray(256);
  }
}
```

it is not even close to the expected c++ byte size. I need to cast my PHP Message correctly so the C++ will reconstruct a proper Message object but I do not know how.

Comment: You generally can't just dump raw structures over the network, you need to *serialize* and *deserialize* them. You could use JSON as a transport format, or if you're looking for something more low-level, consider [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview).

Comment: knowing the length and casting the structure it to a char pointer works fine and is the same as serializing for the purpose of integrity. i just need to know how to make PHP do the same trick for me. I am thinking FFI holds the answer but not so familiar with it.

Comment: That's still really risky due to inevitable [endian issues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) that will crop up when using IoT embedded CPUs. You really want to do this properly rather than half-ass it. FFI only helps when interfacing C++ code directly inside of PHP. Not sure that you'd want to do that as it can massively complicate your deployments.